# random seg fault with calloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, calloc

I'm writing a small command line tool to extract and sort comments in Z80 assembly sources.
I'm blocked with a random seg fault (on MacOS Ventura), lldb shows always the same line, a translation error in calloc.
Seg fault appear sometimes after 1,2...8 iterations (of i) and rarely it does not. No warning during compilation. It is disappointing.

```
ndx[i]->text = (char *) calloc(tsz, sizeof(char));
```

I'd be happy if something can help me understanding the mistake I've made.

Thanks

```
// AX
// my Z80 assembler API extractor
//

// NOTE:
// -----
//
// API extractor will extract all the comment lines following ;;; 
//
// The string following the trigger sequence of LF+';'+';'+';'
// is the sorting label of the paragraph of comments
//
// All the files in the current directory and its childhood are scanned
// Output is sorted on the label used to build the TOC (unimplemented)
//
// Output format is Markdown (unimplemented)
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/errno.h> // lets us directly access errno

// max constants
#define C_MAX 4096      // buffer for fgets (one line from asm source file)
#define I_MAX 1000      // number of entries
#define N_MAX 4096      // buffer for entry name
#define T_MAX 32768     // buffer for entry text 

// entry counter
int i = 0;

// entry structure
struct entry
{
    char *name;
    char *text;
};

// array of pointers to entries
struct entry *ndx[I_MAX];

//
// function to extract API comments in a given filename
// ----------------------------------------------------
//
// trigger is a CRLF+";;;" followed by entry name (to be sorted in a TOC)
// next lines with comment (beginning with ';') are entry text
// any other line ends the text
//
int ApiExtract(char *argv)
{
    // file to parse
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv, "r");
    if(fp == NULL) return 0;

    // state : 0=detect mode, 1=scanning mode
    int scanning = 0;

    // sizes
    int nsz = 0;
    int tsz = 0;

    // buffers
    char chunk[C_MAX];
    char nbuf[N_MAX];
    char tbuf[T_MAX];

    // reset buffers
    memset(chunk, 0, C_MAX);
    memset(nbuf,  0, N_MAX);
    memset(tbuf,  0, T_MAX);

    while(fgets(chunk, C_MAX-1, fp) != NULL)
    {
        if (!scanning)
        {
            // detect mode, look for trigger
            // ;;; trigger sequence for API name
            if (chunk[0] == ';' && chunk[1] == ';' && chunk[2] == ';')
            {
                // trigger found, switch to scanning mode
                scanning = 1;
                // store name (for TOC and entry sorting)
                if (chunk[3]) strncpy(nbuf, &chunk[3], N_MAX-4);
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            // scanning mode
            if (chunk[0] == ';')
            {
                // append line of text
                strncat( tbuf, &chunk[1], T_MAX-strlen(tbuf)-1);
            } 
            else
            {
                // text done, store name and text in a new entry
                ndx[i] = (struct entry *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct entry));

                // set allocation sizes
                nsz = strlen(nbuf)+1;
                tsz = strlen(tbuf)+1;

                // allocate and store name
                ndx[i]->name = (char *) calloc(nsz, sizeof(char));
                strncpy( ndx[i]->name, nbuf, N_MAX-1);

                // allocate and store text
                ndx[i]->text = (char *) calloc(tsz, sizeof(char));
                strncpy(ndx[i]->text, tbuf, T_MAX-1);

                // clear buffers for next iteration
                memset(nbuf, 0, N_MAX);
                memset(tbuf, 0, T_MAX);

                // next entry
                i++;
                if (i>I_MAX) return -1;

                // switch to detect mode
                scanning = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}


}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `fgets(chunk, C_MAX-1, fp)` - why not `fgets(chunk, C_MAX, fp)`?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: in `if (i>I_MAX) return -1;` should be `i >= I_MAX`. You might have a problem if `i == I_MAX` before.

Comment: I used C_MAX-1 to avoid erasing the latest zero in the buffer.

Comment: @elpekos _"`fgets()` reads in at most **one less** than `size` characters"_ and _"A terminating null byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the last character in the buffer"_ - so, no need for `C_MAX-1`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'll try to fix the strncpy(). Unfortunately valgrind is not available for apple M1 CPU. I tried (with no luck) leaks utility. 
I dont understand why lldb shows that the seg fault fires on previous line during calloc ?

Comment: @elpekos Maybe a Linux VM could work? Valgrind works on Linux ARM.

Answer (score 0):

`strncpy()` fills the complete buffer with `0`/`'\0'`, not just one byte after the string. The size of the buffer is given by the last argument.

You say the target buffer has the size of `N_MAX-1`, but the buffer has only the size of `nsz`, which can be shorter than `N_MAX-1`. So `strncpy()` writes after the buffer and you create UB.

Comment: Is there a specification or documention that describes the 0-filling behavior of `strncpy`?